# Redundância de código no meu .xhtml JSF - Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Tenho essa tabela em 2 páginas minhas e acabei por copiar e colar esse código, a única coisa que tive que mudar foi o "bean", em uma eu usei "bean1", na outra eu utilizei "bean2".

Existe alguma solução pra evitar essa redundância de código? Ou é melhor fazer essa cópia mesmo. Tenho a certeza de que sempre será sempre assim.

```
<p:dataTable id="listDataTable" value="#{bean.list}" var="x"
                            widgetVar="dataTableList" filteredValue="#{bean.listFilter}"
                            dataLocale="pt"
                            emptyMessage="Nenhum registro para filtro selecionado"
                            reflow="true" paginator="true" rows="100"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="100,200,500,1000"
                            styleClass="whiteSpaceNowrap">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="List" />
                            </f:facet>

                            <p:column headerText="Coluna 1" filterBy="#{x.coluna1}"
                                filterMatchMode="startsWith" style="text-align: center;"
                                width="90">
                                <f:facet name="filter">
                                    <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('dataTableList').filter()">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}"
                                            noSelectionOption="true" />
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.filter.coluna1}" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{x.coluna1}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Coluna 2" filterBy="#{x.coluna2}"
                                filterMatchMode="startsWith" style="text-align: center;"
                                width="90">
                                <f:facet name="filter">
                                    <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('dataTableList').filter()">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}"
                                            noSelectionOption="true" />
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.filter.coluna2}" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{x.coluna1}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Coluna 3" filterBy="#{x.coluna3}"
                                filterMatchMode="startsWith" style="text-align: center;"
                                width="90">
                                <f:facet name="filter">
                                    <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('dataTableList').filter()">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}"
                                            noSelectionOption="true" />
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.filter.coluna3}" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{x.coluna3}" />
                            </p:column>

                        </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Acho que o melhor caminho é a criação de um composite component. Veja: http://blog.globalcode.com.br/2011/03/jsf-2-composite-components-voce-nao.html

Comment: era exatamente isso que eu procurar. valeu! @NilsonUehara

Comment: se quiser, pode colocar como resposta pra eu aceitar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o melhor caminho é a criação de um custom component

[Link para o artigo](http://blog.globalcode.com.br/2011/03/jsf-2-composite-components-voce-nao.html)